# Make geojson property into a link

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have an external js script that contains a geojson. Within that geojson object there are properties and one of the properties is a url. I need to display that url within my popup as a link that is clickable. Right now, I have the url within my popup, but it's just displayed as string.

I've tried to store the geojson property into a new variable called assemblyWebsite and then input assemblyWebsite into my popup. That still has the variable as string though. I can't figure out how to make that variable into a clickable link, given the fact that the url depends on which polygon the user clicks on. There are several different urls and it can't be one url for each popup.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    var assemblyWebsite = feature.properties.QnsPubAdvocateResults_URL

    layer.bindPopup('<h4>Assembly District</h4>' + ' ' + feature.properties.AssemDist + '</b><br />' + 'Website:' + ' ' + assemblyWebsite);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a href for displaying like a link.

```
var layerGroup = L.geoJSON(data, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<h4>Assembly District</h4>' + ' ' + feature.properties.AssemDist + '</b><br />' + 'Website:' + ' ' + '<a href="'+ 
assemblyWebsite + '">Visit Website</a>' );
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: works! any clue on how to make that link redirect into a new tab rather than the same?

Comment: '<a href="'+ 
assemblyWebsite + '" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>'